# How to change Material UI input underline colour?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI `Select` component that is on a dark background, so for just this one component I'd like to change it so that the text and line colours are all white.  The rest of the `Select` instances should remain unchanged.

While I can get the text and icon to change colour, I can't seem to figure out how to use the `classes` prop to set the underline colour.  My attempts also seem to make the open icon wrap to the next line too.  Here's an example demonstrating the problem:

[image: Edit Material demo]

I've set my style like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  underline: {
    borderBottom: '2px solid white',
    '&:after': {
      // The MUI source seems to use this but it doesn't work
      borderBottom: '2px solid white',
    },
  }
};
```

Then I'm setting it like this:

```
<Select
  classes={{
    underline: classes.underline,     // Does it go here?
  }}
  inputProps={{
    classes: {
      underline: classes.underline,   // Or does it go here?
    },
  }}
>
```

This method does work for the text (not shown above, but in the linked example), it's just the underline colour that I can't get to change.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the underline color of `Select` Component using two options

**1. Overriding with classes**

Create a `<Input />` element using `input` Props and override using classes using `underline` key.

```js
<Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            input={<Input classes={{
              underline: classes.underline,
            }}
             name="age" id="age-helper" />}>
```

I applied this in your sandbox and take a look at this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/owv305w96)

**2. Using `MuiThemeProvider`**

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: green,
  },
});
```

And apply the theme using `<MuiThemeProvider/>`

I have applied both in this sandbox

[Customising Select](https://codesandbox.io/s/r70p3kopmo)

Comment: Is this possible without `createMuiTheme` and without `MuiThemeProvider` ?

Comment: Yes you can override using `classes` prop provided by the HOC component `withStyles`. Refer here https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: in your playbox, I couldn't change the color of the label, after clicking the input. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Could someone help me customize the focused borders to pink, and the label to pink? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ecj1k

Answer (score 12):

In **MUI v5**, you can use the `sx` prop. Below are the examples of 3 different components with customized underline color:

```js
<Input
  sx={{
    ':before': { borderBottomColor: 'red' },
    // underline when selected
    ':after': { borderBottomColor: 'red' },
  }}
/>
```

```js
<TextField
  variant="standard"
  sx={{
    '& .MuiInput-underline:before': { borderBottomColor: 'orange' },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': { borderBottomColor: 'orange' },
  }}
/>
```

```js
<Select
  variant="standard"
  sx={{
    ':before': { borderBottomColor: 'purple' },
    ':after': { borderBottomColor: 'purple' },
  }}
>
```

Another alternative is [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content):

```js
const options = {
  shouldForwardProps: (prop) => prop !== 'underlineColor',
};
const StyledSelect = styled(
  Select,
  options,
)(({ underlineColor }) => ({
  ':before, :after': {
    borderBottomColor: underlineColor,
  },
}));
```

```js
<StyledSelect variant="standard" underlineColor="green">
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This worked for me! Also I added some color for the hover too: `'&.MuiInput-underline:hover:before': {borderColor: 'white'},`

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is simply to turn the underline (and text as well), there's a very simple solution, which also works with many other components (`<Input>`, `<TextField>`, etc.):

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark',
    },
  });
```

It will catch the underline and turn it white.

For details on what this will change, in case you want to override elements of it: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode

(If you've never used a theme before, you'll need to import `createMuiTheme` and wrap your component in it; see https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)