# How to change Material-UI TextField bottom color without using <MuiThemeProvider />

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have a Material UI TextField component that is on a dark background, so for just this one component, I'd like to change it so that the text and line colours are all red. The rest of the TextField instances should remain unchanged.

I am using [@material-ui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) `3.8.1`   and it's [`<TextField />`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/31dda8d7c5917e892b9cf5170489be3e2bc129a5/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L49) component.

I want to avoid having to use `<MuiThemeProvider>`

This is how I have tried based on the recommendation here for the Material-UI [`<Input />`](https://material-ui.com/api/input) component and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620393/how-to-change-material-ui-input-underline-colour?answertab=active#tab-top)

Reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/q9yj0y74z6

Comment: You need to add your classes to the `classes` property not `className`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override the `Input`'s classes, you'll have to use something like this:

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{classes:{underline: classes.underline}}}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to change the `font-family` this way? I am just using the mui `Input`.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Yes, you should be able to do that

Comment: How ? I have tried to set `typography.fontFamily` in `styles` and that didn't help =/

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Define a new class and then use: `input: classes.someClassName`. Those styles will be added directly to the `<input/>` element. You can change the font, text color, etc.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa See my comment above for an example, If you want to use a font from the theme, I think it is something like `theme.typography.fontFamily....`

Comment: I was able using `clasName: `classes.someClassName`

Comment: Titus, maybe can you also help on that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052525/how-to-change-material-ui-textfield-bottom-and-label-color-on-error-and-on-focus

Answer (score 3):

Add this `props` in `<TextField />`

```
InputLabelProps={{
  className: classes.cssLabels
}}
```

Add in `styles`

```
cssLabels: {
  color: "red"
}
```